# weblogic: How to send the same message to different queues?

Tags: queue, jms, weblogic

I need to send the same message to multiple queues within the same server.
Is there any way like forwarding or any thing like that?

Comment: Hello mate, would you mind giving some feedback plz? have you resolved your issue? how did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Topic instead of a Queue. Topic is a publish subscribe way of broadcasting your message to multiple endpoints.

Here is a nice [JMS tutorial](http://techtipsjava.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/jms-on-glassfish-queue-and-topic-with.html) for you including the JMS Client. This tutorial is using the Glassfish server but the implementation should be same for any application server.